# KeyError when trying to plot or histogram pandas data in matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I'm having a problem with generating a basic distribution histogram from an imported csv file. The code works for one set of data from another csv, but not the one that I am interested in, that is essentially the same. Here is the code I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
data = pd.read_csv("idcases.csv")
data1 = data[(data["Disease"] == "Amebiasis") & (data["County"] == "Marin")]
data2 = data[(data["Disease"] == "Amebiasis") & (data["County"] == "Sonoma")]

fig = plt.pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.hist(data1['Population'], bins =10, range = (data1['Population'].min(), data1['Population'].max()))
plt.pyplot.xlabel('Population')
plt.pyplot.ylabel('Count of Population')
plt.pyplot.show()
```

Which yields:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-63303aa9d8a5> in <module>()
      1 fig = plt.pyplot.figure()
      2 ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
----> 3 ax.hist(data1['Population'], bins =10, range = (data1['Population'].min(), data1['Population'].max()))
  4 plt.pyplot.xlabel('Count')
  5 plt.pyplot.ylabel('Count of Population')

C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in hist(self, x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, stacked, **kwargs)
   5602         # Massage 'x' for processing.
   5603         # NOTE: Be sure any changes here is also done below to 'weights'
-> 5604         if isinstance(x, np.ndarray) or not iterable(x[0]):
   5605             # TODO: support masked arrays;
   5606             x = np.asarray(x)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    549     def __getitem__(self, key):
    550         try:
--> 551             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    552 
    553             if not np.isscalar(result):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   1721 
   1722         try:
-> 1723             return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
   1724         except KeyError as e1:
   1725             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer','boolean']:

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3204)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:2903)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3843)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6525)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6463)()

KeyError: 0L
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is a part of what the data that I'm reading in looks like. The code does not work for any of the fields, including 'Count' or 'Rate'

```
       Disease County  Year     Sex  Count  Population   Rate  CI.lower  \
882  Amebiasis  Marin  2001   Total     14      247731  5.651     3.090   
883  Amebiasis  Marin  2001  Female      0      125414  0.000     0.000   
884  Amebiasis  Marin  2001    Male      0      122317  0.000     0.000   
885  Amebiasis  Marin  2002   Total      7      247382  2.830     1.138   
886  Amebiasis  Marin  2002  Female      0      125308  0.000     0.000   
887  Amebiasis  Marin  2002    Male      0      122074  0.000     0.000   
888  Amebiasis  Marin  2003   Total      9      247280  3.640     1.664   
889  Amebiasis  Marin  2003  Female      0      125259  0.000     0.000   
890  Amebiasis  Marin  2003    Male      0      122021  0.000     0.000
```

Comment: This is pandas problem. Please show the content of `data1`.

Comment: The data that you pasted seems to be tab separated (or you formatted after pasting). Make sure that all you csv files have the same separator and supply it as an argument to the read_csv function

Comment: @MikeMüller, the content of data 1 is at the very end.

Comment: @hitzg, I did format after pasting for better viewing. How can I tell which separator is used? Wouldn't a csv file be all comma by nature?

Answer (score 2):

In upgrading from `matploblib-v1.4.3` to `matplotlib-v1.5.0`, I noticed that plotting of `pandas.Series` stopped working,  for example:

```
ax.plot_date(df['date'], df['raw'], '.-', label='raw')
```

would result in a `KeyError: 0` exception.

#### Quick solution:

You need to pass a `numpy.ndarray` instead of a `pandas.Series` to the `plot_date` function:

```
ax.plot_date(df['date'].values, df['raw'].values, '.-', label='raw')
```

#### More details:

Let's look at the full traceback of the exception:

```
# ... PREVIOUS TRACEBACK MESSAGES OMITTED FOR BREVITY ...

C:\Users\pedromdu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py in default_units(x, axis)
   1562 
   1563         try:
-> 1564             x = x[0]
   1565         except (TypeError, IndexError):
   1566             pass

C:\Users\pedromdu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    555     def __getitem__(self, key):
    556         try:
--> 557             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    558 
    559             if not np.isscalar(result):

C:\Users\pedromdu\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   1788 
   1789         try:
-> 1790             return self._engine.get_value(s, k)
   1791         except KeyError as e1:
   1792             if len(self) > 0 and self.inferred_type in ['integer','boolean']:

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:3204)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas\index.c:2903)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3843)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6525)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6463)()

KeyError: 0
```

Notice that the error originates when matploblib tries to do `x=x[0]`.  If your pandas series is not indexed with integers starting at zero this will fail, as this will look for an item with an index value of `0`, rather than for the `0th` element of the `pandas.Series`.

To solve the problem, we need to obtain a `numpy.ndarray` from the data in the `pandas.Series` and then use that for plotting:

```
ax.plot_date(df['date'].values, df['raw'].values, '.-', label='raw')
```

Answer (score 0):

Plots for me:

```
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


s = """       Disease County  Year     Sex  Count  Population   Rate  CI.lower
 Amebiasis  Marin  2001   Total     14      247731  5.651     3.090   
 Amebiasis  Marin  2001  Female      0      125414  0.000     0.000   
Amebiasis  Marin  2001    Male      0      122317  0.000     0.000   
Amebiasis  Marin  2002   Total      7      247382  2.830     1.138   
Amebiasis  Marin  2002  Female      0      125308  0.000     0.000   
 Amebiasis  Marin  2002    Male      0      122074  0.000     0.000   
Amebiasis  Marin  2003   Total      9      247280  3.640     1.664   
Amebiasis  Marin  2003  Female      0      125259  0.000     0.000   
 Amebiasis  Marin  2003    Male      0      122021  0.000     0.000  """
fobj = io.StringIO(s)
data1 = pd.read_csv(fobj, delim_whitespace=True)
plt.hist(data1['Population'], bins =10, range = (data1['Population'].min(), data1['Population'].max()))
plt.xlabel('Population')
plt.ylabel('Count of Population')
plt.show()
```

[image]